# ISPConfig 3 - mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

Tags: php, apache, centos7, ispconfig

I recently restored a server backup and now I get the following error trying to access any website (including the ISPConfig admin interface):

> mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> End of script output before headers: index.php

I have tried to set
opcache.enable = 0

in php.ini which seems to have worked for some, but I still get the same results.

I am using ISPCOnfig 3 on Centos 7 with php 5.4.16 and Apache/2.4.6

Comment: Probably, you need of additional libraries. Take a look at Apache error.log, and report the error lines.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did however find it easier to just reinstall the entire server from scratch. The next time I decide to upgrade php I will do it on a fresh new server and just migrate the content. Lesson learned.